# Acceleration and engine issues

Tags: engine, chevrolet, cavalier, acceleration

So I have a manual 02 Chevy Cavalier with 147000 miles 2.2L. I have been noticing that when I fully step on the gas I get zero acceleration. It gets even worse when I'm in either 4th or 5th gear after 2500 RPM it will just start chugging along and I will even start to lose rpm and mph. I can't figure out what this could be. 
Thank you

Comment: When parked, how does the engine behave when you rev it up?

Comment: Are there any engine fault codes?  When was the last time the car was given a tune up?  Plugs, wires, air filter, etc.  It could also be a clogged cat.

Comment: I checked all plugs seems to be fine I haven't changed my fuel filter in about 3-4 years and just drove from PA to OR and the problem seem to start after I got here . So I'm going to start with changing that and than start working forward after that

Answer (score 2):

There are Various Reasons as to why the car might not accelerate as expected , some of the most common faults for old vehicles are :

- **Faulty Timing Belt**

  This is one of the most common issues for old cars which causes improper or bad acceleration.Check if your timing belt is good.
- **Problem with O2 sensor**

  This sensor analyse the emissions which in turn affect the Air-Fuel mixture going into the engine, if this sensor goes bad then your ECU might think you are either running lean or rich and affect the acceleration.
- **Clogged up Air filter/Problem with Fuel filter.**

  If your car cant breath or consume fuel then it will not accelerate.Also as "rpmerf" says check if the exhaust for possible cats blocking the system.
- **Transmission Issues**

  If all the above work properly and car still does not accelerate properly then you need to check if your clutch is fine and its engaging properly and not slipping.

*As a Side not check the Fuel pump for any possible issue , I had one such problem on an old ford not sure if its frequent.*